# How to fix an error in which Standalone with Beamer and PSTricks produces a blank page?

Tags: beamer, pstricks, standalone

I want to create an animation using features provided by `standalone`, `beamer` and `pstricks`. My attempt is as follows but it produces a blank page. How to fix this error?

```
\documentclass[beamer,preview,border=12pt,multi={pspicture}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}


\def\A{\pspolygon(0,0)(5,0)(5,2)}
\def\B{\pspolygon(0,0)(8,0)(8,3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\begin{pspicture}(13,5)
    \rput(0,0){\A}\pause
    \rput(5,2){\B}\pause
    \pspolygon(0,0)(13,0)(13,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

## Error Messages:

```
Error: /typecheck in --div--
Operand stack:
   1   0   0.0   -0.0179533   a   65781.8
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2022   1   3   %oparray_pop   2021   1   3   %oparray_pop   2009   1   3   %oparray_pop   1865   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   4   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:789/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:159/200(L)--   --dict:96/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 121936
```

## Attempt 1

I did the following, but it does not help as well.

- Installing the newest Ghostscript 9.55.0 for Windows (64 bit).
- Updating TeXLive 2021.
- Invoking `latex -shell-escape filename.tex` more than once.
- Invoking `dvips -t unknown filename.dvi` once.
- Invoking `gswin64c -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o filename.pdf filename.ps` once.
- Removing `standalone` and using `preview` directly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax

\def\A{\pspolygon(0,0)(5,0)(5,2)}
\def\B{\pspolygon(0,0)(8,0)(8,3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{pspicture}(13,5)
    \rput(0,0){\A}\pause
    \rput(8,3){\B}\pause
    \pspolygon(0,0)(13,0)(13,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Attempt 2

Switching to the latest MikTeX does not help too.

## Final

LuaLaTeX works!

Comment: Which  compiler did you use?

Comment: It is probably a good idea to post exactly which larex version you're using or switch to lualatex. There has been issues with xelatex and pstricks lately due to changed security in Ghostscript.

Comment: @daleif: It seems there are no more problems with the latest update of MiKTeX.

Comment: `beamer` and `dvips`  does not work in a lot of cases

Comment: don't use the preview option, preview is currently not really compatible with latex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I removed the `preview` and I got a weird output rather than tight pages as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\A{\pspolygon(0,0)(5,0)(5,2)}
\def\B{\pspolygon(0,0)(8,0)(8,3)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](16,6)
    \rput(0,0){\A}\pause
    \rput(8,3){\B}\pause
    \pspolygon(0,0)(13,0)(13,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Stupid `opacity` and friends work if you add `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}` *before* `\documentclass`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: Great. It works. Thank you very much!